# DependsOn and Cloudformation Custom Resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

From my understanding a resource that has DependsOn specified should be updated if the resource it depends on is updated. I see this for some resources, but it doesn't seem to be working for a custom resource.

I'm working with APIGateway and trying to use a custom resource to deploy the a stage when the resources related to the stage are updated. This is because the included `AWS::ApiGateway::Stage` & `AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment` don't seem to work very well when needed to deploy an update.

I have the following template (snipped for easy reference):

```
<snip>
pipelineMgrStateMachine:
  Type: AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine
  Properties:
    <snip>

webhookEndPointMethod:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
  DependsOn: pipelineMgrStateMachine
  Properties:
    RestApiId: !Ref pipelineMgrGW
    ResourceId: !Ref webhookEndPointResource
    HttpMethod: POST
    AuthorizationType: NONE
    Integration:
      Type: AWS
      IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
      Uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:states:action/StartExecution
      Credentials: !GetAtt pipelineMgrGWRole.Arn
      PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES
      RequestTemplates:
        application/json: !Sub |
          {
            "input": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$'))",
            "name": "$context.requestId",
            "stateMachineArn": "${pipelineMgrStateMachine}"
          }
      IntegrationResponses:
        - StatusCode: 200
    MethodResponses:
      - StatusCode: 200

pipelineMgrStageDeployer:
  Type: Custom::pipelineMgrStageDeployer
  DependsOn: webhookEndPointMethod
  Properties:
    ServiceToken: !GetAtt apiGwStageDeployer.Arn
    StageName: pipelinemgr
    RestApiId: !Ref pipelineMgrGW
<snip>
```

When I update the `pipelineMgrStateMachine` resource I see that the `webhookEndPointMethod` is updated even though nothing changes in the `webhookEndPointMethod`. As expected.

But, `pipelineMgrStageDeployer` is not updated. This is even the case when I make `pipelineMgrStageDeployer` dependent directtly on `pipelineMgrStateMachine`.

Any ideas on why the custom resource is not be updated when a resource it DependssOn is updated? Any other thoughts or insights that might be useful?

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be a misunderstanding on what `DependsOn` is for.

**What's going on**

From the CloudFormation [DependsOn documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html)

> With the DependsOn attribute you can specify that the creation of a specific resource follows another. When you add a DependsOn attribute to a resource, that resource is created only after the creation of the resource specified in the DependsOn attribute.

The reason that your `webhookEndPointMethod` is likely updated when your `pipelineMgrStateMachine` is updated, is because it has an implicit dependency in your `RequestTemplates`

`"stateMachineArn": "${pipelineMgrStateMachine}"`

**How can you make your custom resource get updated**

As for how to have your deployer custom resource update when the state manager updates, you could add a property into your Custom resource that you don't actually use in it, like `PipelineMgStateMachine: !Ref pipelineMgrStateMachine`, for example:

```
pipelineMgrStageDeployer:
  Type: Custom::pipelineMgrStageDeployer
  DependsOn: webhookEndPointMethod
  Properties:
    ServiceToken: !GetAtt apiGwStageDeployer.Arn
    StageName: pipelinemgr
    RestApiId: !Ref pipelineMgrGW
    PipelineMgStateMachine: !Ref pipelineMgrStateMachine
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying and the reference worked great!

I was confused because I saw this note in the DependsOn documentation:

_During a stack update, resources that depend on updated resources are updated automatically. AWS CloudFormation makes no changes to the automatically-updated resources, but, if a stack policy is associated with these resources, your account must have the permissions to update them._

But obviously that did mean what I thought it meant.